# Horizontal list inside panel-footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, horizontallist

I've stuck for a long time at something pretty simple for some freaking reason.

I'm setting a bootstrap 3 layout and I want to style a panel footer according to my requirements. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time to put a horizontal ul inside the footer, with center aligned text in each li.

Here's the current code:

```css
    h1 {
      font-size: 26px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 5px;
      font-family: "Verdana";
    }
    h3 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: "Arial";
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bot: 10px;
    }
    .trip-stats-list {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .trip-stats-list ul li {
      display: inline;
      border: 1px;
    }
    .panel-footer ul li h1 {
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #ff530d;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .panel-footer ul li h3 {
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
  <ul class="trip-stats-list">
    <li>
      <h1>422</h1>
      <h3>photos</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>14</h1>
      <h3>places</h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's what I want:

[image: horizontal-list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to lose the ul formation to gain the responsiveness I needed.

Here's the final code, (which along with bootstrap's grid classes) gets the visual that was required here.

```css
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
}
h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial";
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bot: 10px;
}
.panel-footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.panel-footer h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #ff530d;
}
.panel-footer h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.col-xs-6:first-child {
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-footer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>422</h1>
      <h3>photos</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>14</h1>
      <h3>places</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for turning down some really good answers, but the specs I had was strict. Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Using your code you just have to add:

```
.panel-footer ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}

.panel-footer {
       text-align: center;
    }
```

This will make the li display next to each other.

If you want to add the line in the middle, you can do the next thing:

HTML

```
<li class="line">
  <h1>14</h1>
  <h3>places</h3>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.line {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Add the class line into the second li

Comment: I don't really know why right now, but this seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: @LePhleg add .panel-footer { text-align: center; } in your css

Comment: I'm afraid `ul` doesn't do the trick here and I'll need to get a grid to be more responsive. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Please add this following style to your style sheet.

```
.panel-footer ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px;
   border-left:1px solid black;
   padding: 0 26px;}
.panel-footer ul li:first-child{
    border:none;}
```

Comment: How could I preserve the `text-align:center` here?

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about doing this is wrapping your code within a navbar, and using that to create a horizontal list (but there probably are better ways out there). To do this, simply create a "nav" object of class "navbar", and wrap all your code inside of it. Sorry, I'm kind of new to HTML, so there's probably a better way to do this, but I think this way is pretty simple, and it would be good if you decide to make each section a seperate link.
I know W3 schools has a really good tutorial on creating a navbar in HTML.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: That would be a bad practice, since nav obj should be used for navigation purposes only. Browsers, such as screen readers for disabled users, can use this element to determine whether to omit the initial rendering of this content. Thanks for answering, tho!